# Useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?) 

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, firefox3.6

I have this sniplet of code in jQuery

```
$element.parent().children().last().hide().show('slide', {direction : 'left'}, 700, function () {
    $element.delay(2000, function() {
        $element.parent().children().last().hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 700);             
        reload_table(question_number);
        //delay ends here
    });
});
```

`delay` is declared as:

```
jQuery.fn.delay = function(time,func){
    return this.each(function(){
        setTimeout(func,time);
    });
};
```

Now I get the error:

> useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)

FF3.x, Firefox 6+ is ok. Any ideas on that? Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There already exists a jQuery-method [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) and it expects a string(queueName) and not a function as parameter.
Choose another name for your delay-method to avoid conflicts.

Comment: sorry to say that but that didnt fix it

Answer (score 17):

I got same error when I wrote

```
setTimeout(updateStatus(), 5000);
```

instead of

```
setTimeout(updateStatus, 5000);
```

Comment: OP is already calling the method correctly! this is not the issue. He is already passing a pointer to a function, in the first argument.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with wsbaser.  I had the additional instance of needed to pass information to the function, and for simplicity used:

```
setTimeout(function(){ updateStatus(myData) } , 5000);
```

The argument needs to be a function and not a function being called.  Firefox caught this error, chrome let it go.

Answer (score 7):

Just for reference if someone stumbles upon this question and is looking for a possible answer. I got the exact same error message as the initial poster because I was mixing up the `setTimeout` arguments order.

This:

```
setTimeout(25, function(){
    spotlight.intro.find('#intro').ellipsis();  
});
```

... gave me the error message. I changed the function to this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    spotlight.intro.find('#intro').ellipsis();
}, 25);
```

And my problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in Firefox 3. It is not handling some elements properly => Element  is completely omitted in the tree and ignored -> hence my original problem

Comment: Very unhelpful and undescriptive answer.